# JavaFX: Drawing a infinite symbol and moving along

Tags: java, animation, javafx, shapes, infinite

I need to create a JavaFX application that generates a path in the form of an infinite symbol, and then create a rectangle that will move across that path. 
So far I know to create a circle and square and with transitionPath to move that rectangle , but how to create an infinity shape? I'm very fresh in JavaFx (and in development as well) so please don't be harsh :)

Here is my code with Circle shape:

```
 import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
 import javafx.animation.Timeline;
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
 import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
 import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
 import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;
 import javafx.util.Duration;

 public class PathTransitionDemo extends Application {
 @Override 
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

 Pane pane = new Pane();


 Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle (0, 0, 25, 50);
 rectangle.setFill(Color.ORANGE);

 Circle circle = new Circle(125, 100, 50);
 circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
 circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

 pane.getChildren().add(circle);
 pane.getChildren().add(rectangle);

 PathTransition pt = new PathTransition();
 pt.setDuration(Duration.millis(4000));
 pt.setPath(circle);
 pt.setNode(rectangle);
 pt.setOrientation(
 PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
 pt.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
 pt.setAutoReverse(true);
 pt.play(); 

 circle.setOnMousePressed(e -> pt.pause());
 circle.setOnMouseReleased(e -> pt.play());

 Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 250, 200);
 primaryStage.setTitle("PathTransitionDemo"); // Unos nayiva pozornice e
 primaryStage.setScene(scene); 
 primaryStage.show(); 
 }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
 }
```

I looked everywhere for some hint, but without luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found on the web an SVG path to draw an "infinity" shape, so replace your `circle` with:

```
SVGPath svg = new SVGPath();
svg.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
svg.setStrokeWidth(1.0);
svg.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
svg.setContent("M 787.49,150 C 787.49,203.36 755.56,247.27 712.27,269.5 S 622.17,290.34 582.67,279.16 508.78,246.56 480,223.91 424.93,174.93 400,150 348.85,98.79 320,76.09 256.91,32.03 217.33,20.84 130.62,8.48 87.73,30.5 12.51,96.64 12.51,150 44.44,247.27 87.73,269.5 177.83,290.34 217.33,279.16 291.22,246.56 320,223.91 375.07,174.93 400,150 451.15,98.79 480,76.09 543.09,32.03 582.67,20.84 669.38,8.48 712.27,30.5 787.49,96.64 787.49,150 z");
```

and use it for drawing, transition and event catching.
You may need to adapt it to your need.

If you are looking for better "infinity" shapes, then search for "lemniscate".

Comment: Jean-Baptiste Yunès thank you so much for helping this young enthusiasts! It works like a charm :)